# Getting undefined for a variable even after defining it in a callback

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-maps, callback, synchronous

I am using the following code for distance matric API for Google Maps, by using the `google-distance-matrix` API. The code is as follows:

```js
app.get("/users", (req, res) => {
    // console.log(req.query);
    // res.send(req.query);
    const origins = [`${req.query.origin}`];
    const destinations = [`${req.query.dest}`];
    var dist;
    let carbonEstimate;
    try {
        // distance matrix calculation
        distance.matrix(origins, destinations, (err, distances) => {
            // console.log("Calculating distance...");
            if (err) {
                console.log(err);
                res.status(404).send("Error");
                return;
            }
            if (!distances) {
                res.send("No distance calculated");
                return;
            }
            dist = distances.rows[0].elements[0].distance.text.split(" ");
            console.log(dist);
        });
        console.log(dist);
        res.send("OK");
    }
    catch(err) {console.log(err); res.send("ERROR");}
});
```

The output on the console is as follows for the valid origin and destination 320 km apart:

```
undefined
["320", "km"]
```

Also, I do not want to send the distance, there are some other operations that will happen after the distance is calculated.

I understand that it is being created asynchronously, but I have no idea how to fix it. What should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for your problems is because of async execution and you not waiting for it. Here's what happens:

```js
// you define GET /users route, and whenever someone enters it, the callback is executed
app.get("/users", (req, res) => {
    // console.log(req.query);
    // res.send(req.query);
    const origins = [`${req.query.origin}`];
    const destinations = [`${req.query.dest}`];
    var dist;
    let carbonEstimate;
    try {
        // distance matrix calculation
        // here you call ASYNC method (distance.matrix), which might take some time to execute
        // it's result would be handled with the callback
        // so js CONTINUES with the next line
        distance.matrix(origins, destinations, (err, distances) => {...});
        // here you print dist, but since the callback for distance.matrix
        // is NOT yet called (operation not done), the value is undefined
        console.log(dist);
        // you're sending the response BUT distance is not yet calculated
        res.send("OK"); // <-- MOVE this
    }
    catch(err) {console.log(err); res.send("ERROR");}
});
```

If you'd like to send back the distance, you **must** put `res.send` **inside** the callback of the `distance.matrix`:

```js
distance.matrix(origins, destinations, (err, distances) => {
  // console.log("Calculating distance...");
  if (err) {
    console.log(err);
    res.status(404).send("Error");
    return;
  }
  if (!distances) {
    res.send("No distance calculated");
    return;
  }
  dist = distances.rows[0].elements[0].distance.text.split(" ");
  console.log(dist);
  res.send("OK"); // -- you send the response AFTER distance calculated
});
```

Comment: As mentioned, I understand it happens because of asynchronous behaviour. Also, I have updated the question on what will happen to the `dist` variable. I will not send it but use it for a different use.

Comment: Well now that you know **where** you can have your variable defined, you can continue with your new code, which is not shared here :) Just continue writing code **inside** the callback and then, at the end, send the result.

Comment: Let's just say I have to use another API that will take the distance returned by the google API. I tried what you said and the problem still persists because of that other API.

Comment: As you posted above, there are two `console.log` statements. First one prints undefined (actually it's the last one in the code), and the second one (inside the callback) prints proper values. Put your code **right there**. There's an answer and there's supposed to be a single question in this thread.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I did what you said and it worked! :)

Answer (score 1):

You can only send one response per request. Since `res.send("OK")` sits outside your callback code, it will run first and fulfill the request meaning the callback will never happen.

Comment: The callback is happening asynchronously. So the `dist` variable is to getting updated.

Comment: No it isn't and the other answer, which you accepted, spells out why.

Comment: Sorry about my misunderstanding!